# Firebase database filtering with multiple values

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, querying

On Firebase Youtube channel there is a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs) showing how to convert common SQL queries to Firebase.

The last query is to select all users with `age = 28` and who lives in Berlin. So to get them, we need to create an index, like `28_Berlin` for user, because we cannot use more than one ordering function.

But what should I do if I want to find all user with `age >= 28` here?

And what to do if I need to give users ability to find each other, depending on their interests, age, location, gender? For example, if someone wants to find a male, who is interested in programming and cars, lives in New York and is from 25 to 32 years old?

Seems like I'm in a serious trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You might find some help from [Querybase](https://github.com/davideast/Querybase)